# AJAX call responseText empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a small,simple application.Its on Tomcat 7.Testing on Firefox browser.
My html page resides in

%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\examples\servlets.
So, I access my html page using the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/userinputs.html
```

My java servlet(calls a third party API and returns a text/html response) resides in %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes.

I am using AJAX call in my js file to call this servlet via the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/challengetask
```

The responseText returned is empty.If I access the servlet from browser,I can see the response.
I did go through the same-domain policy and searched 
the internet for similar problems.However, I am unable to figure out as to why the responseText is empty and what EXACTLY is the problem.

My AJAX call :

```
var request =false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
 try{
 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}
catch(e){
} 
} 
}   


if(request){
 request.open("GET",url,true);
 request.onreadystatechange = callBack;
 request.setRequestHeader("Connection","Close");
 request.setRequestHeader("Method","GET"+url+"HTTP/1.1");
 request.send();
}
else {
alert("Sorry could not create an XMLHttpRequest");
}
}
function callBack(){
if(request.readyState == 4){
    if(request.status == 200){
    alert(request.responseText);
}
} }
```

P.S: Both the html and js are in the same folder.
Please help.

Comment: Can you post your ajax call?

Comment: do yourself a favor and add jQuery to your page.  AJAX is easier and more reliable across browsers with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there's unwanted curly bracket (see like in the and of my snippet), remove it.
Second thing is why are you using connection=close, remove it if you don't really need it.

```
if(request){
 request.open("GET",url,true);
 request.onreadystatechange = callBack;
 request.setRequestHeader("Connection","Close");
 request.setRequestHeader("Method","GET"+url+"HTTP/1.1");
 request.send();
}
else {
    alert("Sorry could not create an XMLHttpRequest");
}
}
```

Comment: Fixed it by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1.